# Show that these metrics induces the same topology on X

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of positive integers. Let $d_1$ be the usual metric space on $X$ and $d_2$ be the discrete metric on $X$. Define $d_3:X\times X \rightarrow R$ by $d_3(m,n)=|\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}|$ for $m,n\in X$. Prove that $d_3$ is also a metric on $X$ and $d_1,d_2,d_3$ all induce the same topology on $X$.

I've proved that $d_3$ is also metric.. But I could not proved that all of these induces the same topology. I know that, in order to prove that, these metrices induces that the same topology... I have to prove that all are equivalent metrices. I am stuck at this part.

Comment: *Hint:* Try to show this metrics are equivalent. What can you deduce from that?

Comment: I am stuck at this part...

Comment: whoops, didn't ready the last paragraph properly, my bad. Do you mean $d_3(m,n)= \Vert \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n} \Vert$ ? If yes: There is an obvious upper bound for this metric.

Comment: It is true that equivalent metrics (in the sense that $c d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) \leq C d(x,y)$ for constants $c$ and $C$ and all $x$ and $y$) induce the same topology but two metrics can be not equivalent and still induce the same topology. For example, you cannot have $d_1(x,y) \leq C d_2(x,y)$ for some  $C$ and all $x$ and $y$ because $d_2$ is bounded and $d_1$ is not.

Comment: yes @noctusraid

Comment: Ok try do bound $d_3$ from below and above with $d_1$ by observing a general bound of $d_3$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I don' know. but yes there is an another way to prove it using open ball. That means take an open ball in first metric space and find an open ball in another metric space , which contains it and vice-versa..

Comment: I'd suggest you go on with the equivalence in this exercise.

Comment: Right and notice that in the discrete metric every singleton is an open ball. You might want to prove that this is true for the other two metrics, too.

Comment: @noctusraid I think I can prove that $d_1$ is equivalent to $d_2$. Since $d_2(x,y)\times $ (-ve constant)$\leq |y-x|$ . But how to prove the equivalence of $d_1$ and $d_3$

Answer (score 1):

I'll give one equivalence and edit this answer if OP struggles with the others:

**Claim:** $d_2 \tilde{} \space d_3$ with the notation as in the question.

Proof:

Observe that $d_3(m,n)= \vert \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n} \vert \leq 1$ for all positive integers $m,n$. Therefore we have:

$$d_3(m,n) \leq d_2(m,n) \leq 2d_3(m,n)$$ 
since (w.l.o.g $n >m$):

$$ 2\vert \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n} \vert=\frac{2}{m}-\frac{2}{n}=\frac{2(n-m)}{mn}= 1+\frac{2n-(mn+2m)}{mn}$$ and because

$$1 \geq \frac{m}{2}+ \frac{m}{n} \implies 2n \geq mn+2m$$

we can conclude the equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

$|1/m-1/n|$ <$|m-n|$ So these two are equivalent.
Since $m,n$ are Positive Integers.

and $ |m-n|\geq d_2$ Since $m,n$ are positive integers so least value is zero. All all the Equivalent metrices.

Therefore, all metrics are equivalent. 
and hence induces the same topology.

Comment: you are not allowed negative $C$'s for your constants when showing equivalence of metrics. They need to be strictly positive.

Comment: @noctusraid oh ! they I have to rethink about it... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

All metrics induce the discrete topology (i.e. all sets are open). Forget about any equivalence of metrics, this is a stronger requirement (which does not hold in this case) that is not needed for equivalence of topologies

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/574047)

Comment: It is not a complete answer, yes. However, it tells the author that their previous approaches (as provided in comments to OP and two previous answers) are doomed to fail, and gives him a hint that is straightforward to verify and that implies the solution. I did neither criticize the question nor did I ask for clarification.